# Entity Framework 4 Include + Table joining does not work together

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to select the employee with loaded photo and telephone entities. 
I am using such query:

```
var empl = from user in ObjectContext.Users
                           from employee in ObjectContext.Employees.Include("Photo").Include("HomeTelephone")
                           where
                               user.Id == userId &&
                               employee.Id == user.EmployeeId &&
                               employee.Deleted == false &&
                               employee.OwnerOrganizationId == Singleton.OrganizationId
                           select employee;

var result = empl.FirstOrDefault();
```

the result have nulls for Photo and HomeTelephone properties, but has PhotoId and HomeTelephone set...

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this solves your problem.

```
User user;

using (var ctx = new Model1Container())
{

    user = ctx.UserSet
               .Include("Employee")
               .Include("Employee.Photo")
               .Include("Employee.Telefon")
               .Single(x => x.Id == id);  
}
Console.Out.WriteLine(user.UserName);
Console.Out.WriteLine(user.Employee.Telefon.First().Number);
Console.ReadLine();
```